# how to put 4 control on a line in asp.net?

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have two labels and two text boxes and I want put those control on a line without position absolute

```
<div id="divlbluser" >
    <asp:Label CssClass="lbl" ID="lblUser" runat="server" Text="نام کاربری:"></asp:Label>
</div>
<div id="divtxtuser" >
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="txt" ID="txtUser" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div id="divlblpass" >
    <asp:Label CssClass="lbl" ID="lblPass" runat="server" Text="رمز عبور:"></asp:Label>
</div>
<div id="divtxtpass">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="txt" ID="txtPass"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you having individual items in div, remove div and they will all in same line. otherwise set style="float:left;" in all three div

Comment: float left dont work true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put them in separate divs.

```
<div>
   <asp:TextBox CssClass="txt" ID="txtUser" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Label CssClass="lbl" ID="lblPass" runat="server" Text="رمز عبور:"></asp:Label>
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="txt" ID="txtPass"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

See example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X95y4/)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS

```
<style>
#divtxtuser, #divlblpass, #divtxtpass { float: left; }
</style>
```